# How to check if a specific user is self deafend

Tags: discord.py

I need a way to check if a certain user is self deafend or not. I know there is `.selfDeaf` but I dont know how to put it into a command, it needs to be a `client.event` command and for ease of access it should return a boolean. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example using a command decorator

```py
@client.command()
async def isdeaf(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    if user.voice:
        if user.voice.self_deaf:
            await ctx.send(f"{user} have deafened themselves!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"{user} currently isn't in a voice channel.")
```

---

**References:**

- [`Member.voice`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.voice)
- [`discord.VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState)
- [`VoiceState.self_deaf`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState.self_deaf)